# Sync Berkeley MBOX file with Evolution?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, postfix, xubuntu, evolution, mbox

I set up a remote email system (so that I can have emails sent to my server). Now I mount the storage location of emails received with sshfs and have the mbox file on my local machine, however the import of the file is a one time imoort and does not automatically sync when another email is received.

Is there a way I can get evolution to reload/sync with a particular mbox file whenever it is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically everyone uses IMAP for this purpose (or POP3 for one-way importing) – set up [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) or another IMAP daemon on your remote server, and configure it in Evolution. Dovecot can use mbox as a storage backend (although Maildir is usually much more efficient).